# Link Error with MIC.o file

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, icc, xeon-phi

While linking the sources of an application for the MIC with the Intel C++ (icpc) compiler i got an error.

intel-icc/2013-64 Version:

```
SOMETHINGMIC.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_ZN9__gnu_cxx21__atomic_add_dispatchEPii' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
x86_64-k1om-linux-ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

intel-icc/2015-64 Version:

```
 SOMETHINGMIC.o: In function `std::locale::facet::_M_add_reference() const': /usr/linux-k1om-4.7/linux-k1om/../x86_64-k1om-linux/include/c++/4.7.0 bits/locale_classes.h:402: undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__atomic_add_dispatch(int*, int)'
 SOMETHINGMIC.o: In function `std::locale::facet::_M_remove_reference() const': /usr/linux-k1om-4.7/linux-k1om/../x86_64-k1om-linux/include/c++/4.7.0 bits/locale_classes.h:409: undefined reference to __gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch(int*, int)'
 SOMETHINGMIC.o: In function `std::locale::_Impl::_M_add_reference()': /usr/linux-k1om-4.7/linux-k1om/../x86_64-k1om-linux/include/c++/4.7.0/bits/locale_classes.h:511: undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__atomic_add_dispatch(int*, int)'
 SOMETHINGMIC.o: In function `std::locale::_Impl::_M_remove_reference()': /usr/linux-k1om-4.7/linux-k1om/../x86_64-k1om-linux/include/c++/4.7. /bits/locale_classes.h:518: undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch(int*, int)'
 SOMETHINGMIC.o: In function `std::ios_base::_Callback_list::_M_add_reference()': /usr/linux-k1om-4.7/linux-k1om/../x86_64-k1om-linux/include/c++/4.7.0/bits/ios_base.h:475: undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__atomic_add_dispatch(int*, int)'
 SOMETHINGMIC.o: In function `std::ios_base::_Callback_list::_M_remove_reference()': /usr/linux-k1om-4.7/linux-k1om/../x86_64-k1om-linux/include/c++/4.7.0/bits/ios_base.h:483: undefined reference to `__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch(int*, int)'
```

What is it?

Comment: Can you post the commands you used to build your code? It would be helpful for figuring out where things are going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @froth Just using the ipcp with openmp
Somehow, the the error depends on the order of compile .o files. But there of course are no dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

```
__gnu_cxx::__atomic_add_dispatch(int*, int);
```

is required to be linked with.

Comment: I dont do an atomic add. the only thing is an #pragma offload_transfer target(mic:0) -> so, it generates a MIC.o file

Comment: @SScholl, but the linker error that you posted says this function is missing